# Is there a way to replace all values that appear on another table in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, replace

I need to make a query to get all records whose score is 70 or more and replace all nicknames with their corresponding proper name. I'm using MySQL

#### Table A

| name | score |
| --- | --- |
| Nick | 75 |
| Kate | 76 |
| Robert | 49 |
| John | 91 |
| Jenny | 87 |
| Bill | 29 |
| Gabrielle | 57 |
| Taylor | 88 |
| Joseph | 68 |

The desired output should be the following:

#### Query Result

| name | score |
| --- | --- |
| Nicholas | 75 |
| Kate | 76 |
| John | 91 |
| Jennifer | 87 |
| Taylor | 88 |

*Notice that the names **Nick** and **Jenny** were replaced.*

Currently, the way I'm doing it is using `REPLACE` but that doesn't scale very well so I was wondering if there's a way to get the nicknames from Table B and use it on my query. My current query looks like this:

```sql
SELECT
-- repeat this for every nickname
  REPLACE(REPLACE(name,'Nick','Nicholas'),'Jenny','Jennifer') AS name, 
  score
FROM
  table_a
WHERE
 score >= 70;
```

#### Table B

| nickname | proper_name |
| --- | --- |
| Nick | Nicholas |
| Jenny | Jennifer |
| Bill | William |
| Gaby | Gabrielle |

Comment: Add the tag for the dbms you are using

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use a left join to look up the proper name for each row in table_a.  If the proper name isn't found, it will be null, so you use coalesce to use the original name:

```
select coalesce(proper_name, name) as name, score
from table_a
left join table_b on table_b.nickname=table_a.name
where score >= 70
```